# Why some ads is not breaking down by link_url_asset

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I am trying to do a breakdown by link_url_asset an Ads, but some of my ads are not working.

As I can show, the first ads is working:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/6208361401207/insights?fields=impressions,spend&access_token=mytoken&breakdowns=link_url_asset&time_range[since]=2020-09-14&time_range[until]=2020-09-20](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/6208361401207/insights?fields=impressions,spend&access_token=mytoken&breakdowns=link_url_asset&time_range%5Bsince%5D=2020-09-14&time_range%5Buntil%5D=2020-09-20)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "impressions": "70100",
            "spend": "545.98",
            "date_start": "2020-09-14",
            "date_stop": "2020-09-20",
            "link_url_asset": {
                "website_url": "https://tkees.com/products/glitters",
                "display_url": "www.tkees.com",
                "id": "6207957961207"
            }
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
        }
    }
}
```

The second one, with the same setup, is showing me nothing:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/6212424077007/insights?fields=impressions,spend&access_token=mytoke&breakdowns=link_url_asset&time_range[since]=2020-09-14&time_range[until]=2020-09-20](https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/6212424077007/insights?fields=impressions,spend&access_token=mytoke&breakdowns=link_url_asset&time_range%5Bsince%5D=2020-09-14&time_range%5Buntil%5D=2020-09-20)

```
{
"data": []
}
```

The only difference between both is, the second example is now paused, but I have insights to track.

In the image, bellow is possible to see both ads have a link:
[image]

Is something more I can add to see results in the second case?